# JOINS in DROOLS

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

I have two data objects.
1.) `Customer` ( `cust_id`, `cust_type`, `first_name`, `middle_name` )
2.) `accnt_prtcpnt` ( `cust_id`, `accnt_id`, `ap_first_name` ).

I need to write a Drools rule on `ap_first_name` field in the `accnt_prtcpnt` pbject which says that if the `cust_type` is "AV" in the customer object then the `ap_first_name` should not be null. I am new to Drools and not sure how to go about it. The two data objects can be joined using the common field `cust_id`. Also i am using KIE workbench.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your rule could looks like this:

```
rule "sample rule"
when
    $customer : Customer( cust_type == "AV" )
    accnt_prtcpnt( cust_id  == $customer.cust_id, ap_first_name == null)
then
    // do any action you need
end
```

You can use either plain DRL editor from workbench or some of guided editors (guided rule, guided decision table, ...)